# Node/Express Multer upload system not loading uploaded files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i have made an images upload system in nodejs using express ajax and multer.
The images load exactly in the destination set by me and with the name set by me. The problem is that when I go to the page where it should show the uploaded pictures it tells me that it doesn't find them (404 NOT FOUND). But after i press CTRL + F5 the images appear.

How can I do it after uploading the pictures, when I go to the page where the pictures should be displayed to appear without having to refresh the FTP or pressing CTRL + F5?

Here are my code

> **Ajax handler from create profile page**

```
$(".b_cr_md").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var v_fm_dt = new FormData();
        if (v_fm_dt) {
          if ($('.up_im').is(':visible')){
            var _image = document.getElementById('imgInp');
            var m_nm = $('#m_nm').val();
            if (m_nm.length < 1) {
              alert('Please select a name');
            } else {
              v_fm_dt.append('modelname', m_nm);
              for ( i = 0 ; i < _image.files.length; i++) {
                var file = _image.files[i];
                v_fm_dt.append('pictures', file);
              }
              $.ajax({
                url: '/dashboard/actions/models/createmodel/'+m_nm,
                type: 'POST',
                method: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: v_fm_dt,
                success: function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                }
              });
            }

          } else {
            alert("You didn't select the pictures");
          }
        }
      });
```

> **Router function:**

```
router.post('/actions/models/createmodel/:modelsname', function (req, res, next) {

const name = req.params.modelsname;
const custom_folder = './public/images/models/'+name;
if (!fs.existsSync(custom_folder)){
  fs.mkdirSync(custom_folder);
}
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, custom_folder);
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    if (!req.headers.index){
      req.headers.index = 1;
    }
    cb(null, name.toLowerCase() + '_' + (req.headers.index++) + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

let upload_im = multer({ storage: storage}).array('pictures', 4);
upload_im(req, res, function(err){
  if (err) {
    res.send('error');
  } else {
    res.send('success');
  }
});
```

});

Comment: so you want to have the pictures you upload automatically updated on the web page without pressing `Ctrl + F5` , Is that it?

Comment: Yes !
P.S: I'm developing on web host not local

Comment: But even i press ctrl + f5 the images doesn't appear before i refresh FTP files